# EventListeners, which are defined in another EventListeners in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want to define an `EventListener` after clicking on a `button`.

I set `EventListener` in another `EventListener` and want the child `EventListener` to be listening to `click event` *only after* the parent event was triggered.

Code snippet:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn")
btn.onclick = function() {
  console.log("PARENT")
  document.onclick = function() {
    console.log("CHILD")
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click</button>
```

**Current behavior:**

Parent and child `events` trigger together, even on the first click on the button.

So, even on the first click on the `button` I see `"PARENT" "CHILD"` in console, but I want to see only `"PARENT"`.

**Desired behavior:**

Child `EventListener` should be listening to `click event` *only after* clicking on the `button` element. Thus, I want to see on the first click on the `button` only `"PARENT"` in console and after on subsequent clicks: `"PARENT" "CHILD"`.

Why it works in such way?
Why does the `event`, defined in *child* `EventListener`, trigger with the `event`, defined in *parent* `EventListener`, though *child* `EventListener` should *only start listening* to `click event` when the parent `event` is triggered?

Comment: Look into "event bubbling". First the btn event handler is executed and the document click handler is registered. **Then the event travels UP the dom** until the document is reached. There it will trigger your document onclick handler which has already been registered at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is handled for the button - where the new listener is assigned, then it bubbles up and handles the newly registered handler.

Anyway, it may be easier and more clear to use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to save the click state of the button. for example:

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  console.clear();
  if (evt.target.classList.contains(`btn`)) {
    evt.target.dataset.clicked = 1;
    return console.log(`.btn clicked`);
  }
  
  if (evt.target === document.documentElement) {
    if (!document.querySelector(`.btn`).dataset.clicked) {
      return true;
    }
     
    return console.log(`document clicked`);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn")
btn.onclick = function() {
  console.log("PARENT");
  setTimeout(() => (
    document.onclick = function() {
      console.log("CHILD")
    }
  ), 0);      
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click</button>
```

more content:
[Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)